# MJPEG stream decoder for Universal Windows Platform app

Tags: stream, uwp, mjpeg, decoder

I'm working on a UWP app for school where I'm trying to display a MJPEG stream from my raspberry pi in the application. All the available decoders seem to work for windows phone 8.1 but not for the new UWP apps.

Is there anything I can do to use these streams in my application?

If not, is there a tool I can use to convert the streams and stream them on another port in the right format? This can be for raspberry or just windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197.aspx) is at least [partially supported in a UWP app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592894.aspx#multimedia). And it offers an [MJPEG decoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927.aspx), too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [MJPEG Decoder](https://mjpeg.codeplex.com/releases/view/98065) that supports UWP apps. To use it, we can download [MJPEG Decoder Binaries](https://mjpeg.codeplex.com/downloads/get/535912) and then reference **MjpegProcessor.winmd** in the project.

After this, we can use following code to display the MJPEG stream.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MjpegDecoder mjpegDecoder;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mjpegDecoder = new MjpegDecoder();
        mjpegDecoder.FrameReady += mjpeg_FrameReady;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        mjpegDecoder.ParseStream(new Uri("URI HERE"));
    }

    private async void mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await ms.WriteAsync(e.FrameBuffer);
            ms.Seek(0);

            var bmp = new BitmapImage();
            await bmp.SetSourceAsync(ms);

            //image is the Image control in XAML
            image.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks for your time, gonna try it as soon as possible :)

Comment: @Jay Zou - MSFT: is MjpegProcessor.winmd still work well for now?